# An error with bashful package

Tags: bashful

I would like too use the `bashful` package but an error occured. I wrote this simple code (test.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}
\bash
ls
\END
\end{document}
```

and the compilation failed :

```
L7: I will now print the contents of file test.stderr (if found)
L7: File test.stderr was empty
L7: Proceeding as usual
L7: Checking whether any listings are required
L7: Nothing has to be listed
L7: Defining macro for the contents of the standard output file
L7: Opened file test.stdout
L7: File test.stdoutwas empty
after EOF
L7: bashStdout :=
\bashStdout 

L7: Closing file test.stdout
L7: Defining macro for the contents of the standard error file
L7: Opened file test.stderr
L7: File test.stdoutwas empty
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...nputlineno : bashStderr :=
\bashStderr 

l.7 \END
        ^^M
?
```

I don't figure it out. Is something missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use latex with the `--shell-escape` flag (otherwise bash is prevented from running and you get the error you show)

Also if you want to see the output in the document you need `[stdout]` so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}
\bash[stdout]
ls
\END
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I saw this in other posts, but I didn't understand, untill now.